# Am I in danger of SQL injection if I only allow words from a specific list?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have some code that accesses a table in a SQL Server database:

```
...
if (GetViewNames(connection).Contains(name))
{
    query = "SELECT * FROM [" + name + "]";
}
...
```

Here is "GetViewNames":

```
private List<string> GetViewNames(SqlConnection connection)
{
    List<string> viewNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in connection.GetSchema("Views").Rows)
    {
        // The third element in the "rows" array is the name of the view.
        viewNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
    }

    return viewNames;
}
```

All I want to know is if this code is open to SQL injection. `name` is a string passed through the URL (bad, I know), but it will only ever query the DB if `name` is in my list of tables, right? Or am I missing something here?

I'm no security expert, so please be kind with your responses.

Comment: While I don't know what your primary use is for this, I personally advise against it, regardless of injection. As a simple measure of defense, I've always preferred to reveal as little as possible about my data structure. The less you reveal to prying eyes, the less they can do.

Comment: If you're sure GetViewNames will only return alphanumeric strings (in particular, without the `]` character), then this should be safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Who has access to the creation of connection?

Comment: Why do people not use simple static queries - nothing wrong with it! SQL is not OOP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from creating a view named `users];DROP TABLE [users`. It should be clear what happens when the code is executed with this view name.

If all of your views are named by yourself, it is possible to keep it safe, but I would recommend using `QUOTENAME` just in case.

Comment: Okay, thanks @hvd. The views are all managed by my boss, and I don't think he'll be injecting malicious code.

Comment: FYI, if I recall correctly, T-SQL will not allow an object name to have the close bracket in it, even if it's quoted and escaped.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Perhaps it's version dependent but I am pretty sure I've created such objects for testing in the past. Will check to make sure when I can.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's accepted in the current version of at least the Linux preview, both with brackets and with double quotes. `create or alter view [test]]] as select table_name from information_schema.views where table_name like 'test%';`, and then `select * from "test]";` gives `test]`.